# Как вывести значение массива в input вместо console.log?

Tags: javascript, массивы, консоль, input

Как правильно записать, чтобы значение массива, не все, а одно из, например `myObject[0]`, выводилось в `input`, а не в `console.log`?

```
window.onload = function(){
  myObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ResultM'));
  if (null !== myObject) {
      console.log(myObject[0]);
}};
```

Comment: получить элемент input и изменить его аттрибут value

Answer (score 2):

У Вас фактически уже все было написано, осталось только получить нужный `input` и изменить его значение:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const myObject = ["тест"]
  // const myObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ResultM"))
  if (myObject) { 
    document.querySelector("input").value = myObject[0]
  }
}
```

```html
<input value="" />
```

Comment: выдает ошибку :  Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at window.onload  Что делать?(

Comment: @ArtKom в данном сниппите нету ошибок. Запустите, проверьте